# how to create 2d array with 3 elements from 1d array using python

Tags: python

```
signals=([1998  ,1968  ,1937  ,1827  ,2027,2286  ,2484  ,2266  ,2107  ,1690,1808  ,1927  ,1924  ,1959  ,1889,1819  ,1824  ,1979  ,1919  ,1845,1801  ,1799  ,1952  ,1956  ,1969,2044  ,2100  ,2103  ,2110  ,2375,
    2030  ,1744  ,1699  ,1591  ,1770,1950  ,2149  ,2200  ,2294  ,2146,2241  ,2369  ,2251  ,2126  ,2000,1759  ,1947  ,2135  ,2319  ,2352,2476  ,2296  ,2400  ,3126  ,2304,
    2190  ,2121  ,2032  ,2161  ,2289,2137  ,2130  ,2154  ,1831  ,1899,2117  ,2266  ,2176  ,2089  ,1817,2162  ,2267])

Vectors=[[signals[i-1],signals[i+1],signals[i+3]] for i in range(1,len(signals-4))]
print Vectors

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6f5b7430197d> in <module>()
     16     2190  ,2121  ,2032  ,2161  ,2289,2137  ,2130  ,2154  ,1831  ,1899,2117  ,2266  ,2176  ,2089  ,1817,2162  ,2267])
     17 
---> 18 Vectors=[[signals[i-1],signals[i+1],signals[i+3]] for i in range(1,len(signals-4))]
     19 print Vectors
     20 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'


Expected Output:[[signals[0],signals[2], signals[4]],[signals[1],signals[3],signals[5]],[signals[2],signals[4],signals[6]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your `range` function , you need to parenthesis the `signals` as you want to subtract 4 from the length of `signals` list:

```
range(1,len(signals)-4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your paren is not correctly placed: `len(signals-4)` should be `len(signals) - 4`.